# Google Sheets function Address() results in adding unwanted characters ''! when used in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

If you look at the following table in Column A I have some values that I want to use to make an address reference.  I can successfully accomplish this with the formula in Column C copied down into each cell. I would like to use the more dynamic ArrayFormula so that when even I enter a new row it will populate with the correct Address. However, it's injecting `''!` before my addresses. I don't know what to do to get rid of it.

I have a workaround in another column in row 3 I enter this. `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B3:B), MID(B3:B,4,5),))` however I feel the address should just work without it.  Anyone know why it does the unnecessary injection `''!`.

[link to example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1reKy-UZnHoHubY2YtifaZks3huUAyxtlpXfYgxzWQdY/edit?usp=sharing)

```
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|            | Incorrect but dynamic                                         | Correct if but not dynamic  |  
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Formula -> | ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), ADDRESS(Row(A3:A),A3:A,4,TRUE,),)) | ADDRESS(Row(A3),A3,4,TRUE,) |
|    1       | ''!A3                                                         | A3                          |
|    2       | ''!B4                                                         | B4                          |
|    3       | ''!C5                                                         | C5                          |
|    4       | ''!D6                                                         | D6                          |
|    5       | ''!E7                                                         | E7                          |
|    1       | ''!A8                                                         | A8                          |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(A3:A),A3:A,4,1,),"''!",""),))
```

[image: 5]

Comment: That does give me the correct result.  I can also use my workaround `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), MID(ADDRESS(Row(A3:A),A3:A,4,TRUE,),4,5),))`  and get the same thing.  However I am wondering why it adds `''!` its as if its trying to address a blank sheet. ie `'sheetname'!A3`.  But I don't see any options to omit or add it.

Comment: its a by-product of 2nd parameter of `ADDRESS` formula when in combination with `ARRAYFORMULA`